# Finding position where the next value is larger

Tags: r

I have a data set df, I have a code
`df1 <- df %>% summarise(across(.fns = ~max(which(.x == min(.x[lead(.x) > .x)])), 1)))`
where I would like to find the max position of the min point when the next point is larger than it. For x I would like to get row position at 4, but the result I got with the above code is 8. Is there a way to fix it? Thanks.

```
dput(df) >structure(list(a = c(6, 9, 4, 4, 12, 4, 4, 4), b = c(2, 2, 1, 
1, 6, 6, 8, 5), c = c(3, 3, 9, 2, 4, 5, 19, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


 df> 
  a     b     c
  6     2     3
  9     2     3
  4     1     9
  4     1     2
 12     6     4
  4     6     5
  4     8    19
  4     5     3
```

Desired result >

```
 a    b     c
 4    4     4
```

Comment: What is the relationship between `a`/`b`/`c` in `df` and `x`/`y`/`z` in your expected output?

Comment: Oh sorry, the x,y,z should be a,b,c. I'll edit the ques.

Comment: Ok.  So for each column, you want the row with the smallest value in that column which is followed in that column by the largest value in that column?  Could you adjust your example data so the answer isn't 4 for all columns?  That might make it easier to understand your goal.

Comment: Yeah. I would like to get that result.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should remove `lag(.x) == .x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  summarise(across(.fns = ~{
     inds <- which(lead(.x) > .x)
     inds[which.min(.x[inds])]
  }))

#      a     b     c
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     4     4     4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which` to find the cases where `diff` `>0` and get the position with `which.min`.

```
sapply(df, function(x) {
  i <- which(diff(x) > 0)
  i[which.min(x[i])]
})
#a b c 
#4 4 4
```

or you can use `rle`

```
sapply(df, function(x) {
  y <- rle(x)
  sum(y$lengths[seq(which.min(y$value))])
# cumsum(y$lengths)[which.min(y$value)] #Alternative
})
#a b c 
#4 4 4
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to identify the row with per-column min followed by column max:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(ix = row_number()) %>%
  filter(across(value, ~. == min(.) & lead(.) == max(.))) 
  
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   name [2]
  name  value    ix
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 b         1     3
2 a         4     4
```

Note: Based on the `df` provided, only column `a` has a row for which the column minimum is preceded by the column maximum.

Here's an update on `df` with a value in `b` that satisfies the criteria, to demonstrate the evidence across multiple columns:

```r
df <- structure(list(a = c(6, 9, 4, 4, 12, 4, 4, 4), 
                     b = c(2, 2, 1, 10, 6, 6, 8, 5), 
                     c = c(3, 3, 9, 2, 4, 5, 19, 3)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -8L), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df
# A tibble: 8 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     6     2     3
2     9     2     3
3     4     1     9
4     4    10     2
5    12     6     4
6     4     6     5
7     4     8    19
8     4     5     3
```